# Word for an object involved in a collision?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology, science

I want a word that is used to mean an object involved in a collision, for example, say two tennis balls collide - ball 1 and ball 2 - what would be a word that could describe either ball, only in the context of a collision.

Similarly to how each particle involved in a reaction is a reactant.

Example sentence following the tennis balls:

> The two balls, or _____ in a physics context, collided in mid-air.

Comment: There is [collidant](https://www.amazon.com/Dynamic-Response-Collidant-Impacting-Pressure/dp/124935837X)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In physics, the word **body** is used. Form [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/body):

> *physics* **specialized** a separate object or mass

Example sentences from [Wikipedia's page on collisions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collision#Types_of_collisions) (emphasis mine):

> There are two types of collisions between two **bodies** - 1) Head-on collisions or one-dimensional collisions - where the velocity of each **body** just before impact is along the line of impact, and 2) Non-head-on collisions, oblique collisions or two-dimensional collisions - where the velocity of each **body** just before impact is not along the line of impact.